# uwsgi unable to find the spooler function

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, spooler

I was trying to find out about the [spooler mechanism](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Spooler) of [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) and for that reason I've written a small, dummy web application with [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) (version 1.3.1) and it is running on the latest stable version of [nginx](http://nginx.org/). Everything works as expected. However, in one of my views, I am sending a spool message to the uWSGI container and, I get the following error:

```
[spooler /private/tmp/receiver pid: 4115] managing request uwsgi_spoolfile_on_ozgurv.local_4165_1_0_1338280641_366596 ...
unable to find the spooler function, have you loaded it into the spooler process ?
```

In my testapp/views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from testapp.spool import three_seconds

def call(request):
    three_seconds.spool(a=1, b=2)
    return HttpResponse('spooled')
```

In my testapp/spool.py file:

```
from uwsgidecorators import *

@spool
def three_seconds(*args, **kwargs):
    f = open('/tmp/args.data', 'a')
    f.write(repr(kwargs) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

When I've executed the function 'call' by requesting the url /call/ in the browser, I got the following error:

```
[spooler /private/tmp/receiver pid: 4115] managing request uwsgi_spoolfile_on_ozgurv.local_4165_1_0_1338280641_366596 ...
unable to find the spooler function, have you loaded it into the spooler process ?
```

uWSGI is running with the following parameters:

```
sudo uwsgi --ini ~/uwsgi.ini -b 20000
```

And the content of my uwsgi.ini file looks like follows:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8081
listen = 4096
master = true
processes = 4
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi.pid
enable-threads = true
uid=root
gid=admin
single-interpreter = true
disable-logging = true
buffer-size= 32768
reload-on-as = 10240
reload-on-rss = 512i0
max-requests = 50000
pythonpath = /Users/ozgurv/Developer/warehouse
module = wsgi_handler

plugins = python27,spooler
spooler-processes = 1
spooler = /tmp/receiver
```

I have no clue why it's been complaining about the spooler function and why [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) could not find it. And what does "have you loaded it into the spooler process" mean? How can one load a spooler function in the spooler process's context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use spooler-import = testapp/spool.py

The spooler process will import that module in its process address space

another solution is importing the module in all of the uwsgi processes with

import = testapp/spool.py